# Heroku: Importing data from Postgre dump Error

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am running Heroku Django app with post-gre. On my local machine, I have the same app with local db. Now wanted to import my data from local db to heroku db. I am following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) guide. I have created a dump file from local db using:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mylocaldb > mylocaldb.dump
```

I have uploaded this dump file to Dropbox. On heroku terminal when I enter:

```
heroku pg:backups restore 'link/to/dump/file' DATABASE_URL
```

The output after selecting app is:

```
b008 ---restore---> HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY
Running... 32.8kB
```

It gets stuck on that XX.XkB and no progress after that. It drops all tables in my heroku db, and does nothing after that (I checked using psql).

My question is:

1. How do I check logs for this restore process ? (and hence track the error). `heroku logs --tail` shows nothing related to restore.
2. My local and heroku db have different name. Is that okay ?
3. My local db has lots of Users, foreign key, south migrations and admin logs. Is that okay or one has to remove all of them before dumping ?
4. Do I run "pg:backups restore" before or after running syncdb and and south migrate ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command to get the info for the import:

```
heroku pg:backups info b008
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue where I uploaded the file to dropbox and used the share link as the backup URL. However, I failed to change the `?dl=0` param in the URL to `1` which means Heroku was trying to download an HTML file instead of the database dump.